# jQuery uppercase select option value only

Tags: html, jquery

I have a form with a select element

```
<select name="Course" id="Course" class="form-control input-lg"><option value="">Select Course</option><option value="cyft">Cybersecurity Bootcamp</option><option value="cypt">Cybersecurity Part-Time</option></select>
```

I fill the options with jQuery -

```
$.each(data.result, function(key, value){
        if($.inArray(value.track+ value.format, ids) == -1)
                {
                    ids.push(value.track+ value.format);
                    var item = Courses.find(item => item.id === value.track + value.format);
                    if (item) {
                            html_code += '<option value="'+value.track + value.format + '">'+item.name +'</option>';
                    }
                }
});   
$('#Course').html(html_code);
```

How do I UPPERCASE the **value.track** and **value.format** (*option values*) only, so it looks like below -

```
<select name="Course" id="Course" class="form-control input-lg"><option value="">Select Course</option><option value="CYFT">Cybersecurity Bootcamp</option><option value="CYPT">Cybersecurity Part-Time</option></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your concatenation in `()`, then use `toUpperCase()`:

```
html_code += '<option value="' + (value.track + value.format).toUpperCase() + '">' + item.name + '</option>';
```

Edit: You can improve your code a bit too; you're doing multiple `value.track + value.format`, so assign that to a variable:

```
let trackFormat = value.track + value.format;
if($.inArray(trackFormat, ids) == -1) {
  ids.push(trackFormat);
  var item = Courses.find(item => item.id === trackFormat);
  if (item) {
    html_code += '<option value="' + trackFormat.toUpperCase() + '">' + item.name + '</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.. but why create another variable and use more memory?  (trackFormat)

Comment: So you don't have to type `value.track + value.format` 4 times :) It's a concept known as DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) programming. Plus, I would expect the memory usage  for a single variable vs multiple concatenations is more performant (but I don't know that for sure, and it's likely negligible)

Comment: fair point, but I've always been taught that you shouldn't create variables for the sake of it..

Comment: Totally understandable, and as a teaching point, it makes sense. From a practicality point, I'd go insane if I coded that way... If you have to change your code, say to add `value.example`, you'd currently have to do it in at least 4 spots. If you miss one, you might find yourself in a bit of hot water. With a variable, you only need to change it once, without fear of missing an instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use toUpperCase()  method for example value.toUpperCase() as per your example you can use something like value.track.toUpperCase().

For more reference see [https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_touppercase.asp][1]